# Is There anyway to Render a component from an object? -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

ok guys I have a problem.

I need render a list which has a title and a icon .
and I Want to render it dynamic with map method.

This is the backend api object(Its more than 2 :D )

```js
// icons are Material UI Icon component
const list = [
{title: 'Vehicle', icon: 'DirectionsCarFilledOutlined'},
{title: 'Electronic', icon: 'PhoneIphoneOutlined'},
]
```

What I have to do is to render this icon `COMPONENT` dynamic

something like this

```
import {
  DirectionsCarFilledOutlined,
  PhoneIphoneOutlined,
} from "@mui/icons-material";


const list = [
{title: 'Vehicle', icon: 'DirectionsCarFilledOutlined'},
{title: 'Electronic', icon: 'PhoneIphoneOutlined'},
]

              {list.map(({ title, icon }) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <p>{title}</p>
                    <div>{<icon />}</div> // Problem is here. IDK How to render it 
                  </div>
                );
              })}
```

I Wrote switch case for this problem but that's bad and if we add new items to api those lists won't have icon.

Is there anyway to render this Icons dynamic ?

Comment: Capitalize the name. ({icon}) => { const Icon = icon; ... then render it <Icon /> }

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Ty for ur replay. I tried that but in the inspect element instead of component we have ```<phoneiphoneoutlined></phoneiphoneoutlined>```

Comment: icon value has to be component, not string. If the data is from server, you have to create an object where you get the component itself based on string value. Something like: components: {'DirectionsCarFilledOutlined': DirectionsCarFilledOutlined, ...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using `React.lazy` to LazyLoad icons, given that the icon value corresponds to an exact path from `@mui/icons-material`.

To do so, first we need to define a lazy function that can return non-default exports, since `React.lazy` expects to return a default import

```
// iconName is still undefined, but we'll get to it
const Icon = lazy(() =>
  import("@mui/icons-material").then(module => ({ default: module[iconName] }))
);
```

Then, we'll write an Item component, which receives iconName as a prop and LazyLoads it, utilizing `React.Suspense` to allow for the component to be rendered.

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react'

const Item = ({title, iconName}) => {
  const Icon = lazy(() =>
    import("@mui/icons-material").then(module => ({ default: module[iconName] }))
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
          <Icon/>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You should then import `Item` inside your component and return Items from your map.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could be the solution for you.

You can directly set the `icon element` imported from `@mui/icons-material` as the value of the `icon` of the `list` item.

```
import {
  DirectionsCarFilledOutlined,
  PhoneIphoneOutlined,
} from "@mui/icons-material";


const list = [
  {title: 'Vehicle', icon: DirectionsCarFilledOutlined},
  {title: 'Electronic', icon: PhoneIphoneOutlined},
]
```

... in render part

```
          {list.map(({ title, icon }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <div><icon /></div> // Problem is here. IDK How to render it 
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

Comment: ty for your replay. but the data is coming from backend and everything is string